# Batch find and replace only on lines that contain a specific text

Tags: batch-file, replace

I'm trying to do a "find and replace" into a text file from batch but only on specific lines, as such:

**Before:**

```
7,U7k956ykBJ,"GenericLine"
7,SwNZVX7SwPA2,"GenericLine"
7,783bMsWVSJZ8,"LineToReplace"
7,PiUcP84ujF5z,"GenericLine"
```

**After:**

```
7,U7k956ykBJ,"GenericLine"
7,SwNZVX7SwPA2,"GenericLine"
2,783bMsWVSJZ8,"LineToReplace"
7,PiUcP84ujF5z,"GenericLine"
```

So, to be clearer, I'd like to replace that "7," to a "2," if the line contains "LineToReplace"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, batch is kind of clunky to be doing this in - consider PowerShell.

But, for batch, this script:

1. Enables delayed variable expansion.
2. Sets DestinationFile.txt to 0 bytes.
3. Loops via `FOR` through the lines of a file named SourceFile.TXT.
4. Places each line in variable Var.
5. Replaces any double quotes in Var with two single quotes (To avoid issues with IF statement.).
6. Replaces search text in Var with nothing, saving results into Alt.
7. If Alt does not equal Var, then Var had the desired text, get fresh unaltered copy of the line in Var, Echo out the number 2 followed by all of Var except first char.
8. Else Var did not have the desired text, so echo out the line as is and unaltered.
9. Sends output to DestinationFile.txt

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

NUL >DestinationFile.txt 2>NUL
FOR /F "EOL=~ TOKENS=* DELIMS=~" %%L IN (SourceFile.txt) DO (
    SET Var=%%L
    SET Var=!Var:"=''!
    SET Alt=!Var:LineToReplace=!
    IF NOT "!ALT!" == "!Var!" (
        SET Var=%%L
        ECHO;2!Var:~1!
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO;%%L
    )
) >>DestinationFile.txt
```

**EDIT:**  As I said, batch, in my opinion, is kind of clunky.  It turns out that the solution I submitted fails to work correctly if there is an exclamation mark `!` in the text in the source file. While I'm sure this issue can be overcome with a true batch script, I think it is time to consider an alternative.

Here is a Batch/PowerShell hybrid version:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "switch -Regex -File 'SourceFile.txt' { '^.+?(?<RestOfLine>,.*LineToReplace.*)$' {'2'+$Matches.RestOfLine} default {$_}}" >"DestinationFile.txt"
```

Comment: It does work, but I just noticed after a while, that if there is a "!", it acts weird. (Weird as it just ignores the following characters until a quote)

Comment: To clarify, you mean that if the SourceFile.txt has a `!`, then it ignores all characters until next `"`?  If that is what you mean, then it sounds like it needs to be reworked to properly deal with `!`.  Let me know if that is the situation.

Comment: Yes, that is the situation

Comment: @Xemles, if you require a 100% batch solution, I suggest creating a new question with the original batch script in my answer and ask if there is a better solution that can deal with exclamation marks in source file text.  But, if you you are fine with a batch/PowerShell hybrid then take a look at the edit to the answer.  The hybrid code uses RegEx to check if the text of each line, after the first `,` contains the desired text.